# Jade, Angular and ngSwitch

Tags: angularjs, pug, angular-ui

I have an issue using `ng-switch` for some reason the view won't switch even if the model is updated. It always display the default view (which is there for testing only), everything is supposed to work OK in full html as tested here http://plnkr.co/edit/fKlPKy?p=preview so I suppose it's from jade:

```
    .btn-group(data-toggle='buttons-radio', style='float:right; margin-right:20px;')
      .btn(ng-model='displayType', btn-radio="'grid'")
        i.icon-th
      .btn(ng-model='displayType', btn-radio="'list'")
        i.icon-align-justify

  .switch(ng-switch, on='displayType')
    .switch(ng-switch-when='grid')
      include gridView
    .switch(ng-switch-when='list')
      include listView
    pre(ng-switch-default) {{displayType}}
```

I can see in the default view that the `displayType` is correctly updated to 'grid' or 'list' depending on the selected radio

Updated with full HTML of the area:

```
<div ng-controller="cardCtrl" class="container ng-scope">
  <div class="card-list-header">
    <div class="card-search">
      <div align="center" class="input-append">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchterm" placeholder="Type in filter criteria and press Enter..." ui-keypress="{13:'keypressCallback($event)'}" class="input-xxlarge ng-valid ng-dirty"><span ng-click="addCard()" class="add-on">+</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-toggle="buttons-radio" style="float:right; margin-right:20px;" class="btn-group">
      <div ng-model="displayType" btn-radio="'grid'" class="btn ng-pristine ng-valid active"><i class="icon-th"></i></div>
      <div ng-model="displayType" btn-radio="'list'" class="btn ng-pristine ng-valid"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch="ng-switch" on="displayType" class="switch">
    <!-- ngSwitchWhen: grid -->
    <!-- ngSwitchWhen: list -->
    <!-- ngSwitchDefault: ng-switch-default -->
    <pre ng-switch-default="ng-switch-default" class="ng-scope ng-binding">grid</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your `.switch` inside some other controller or scope (maybe inside another ng-switch or ng-repeat or ng-include or something else that creates its own scope?)

Comment: @MarkRajcok it's right inside an `ng-controller` which itself is in an `ng-view`

Comment: Is the button group inside the ng-view also?

Comment: @MarkRajcok yes it is. What I don't get is why the `{{displayType}}` update correctly but the ng-swicth doesn't trigger

Comment: Looks like you are mixing Jade's switch with angular's switch...

Comment: @sza I don't intend to use any jade syntax, it's just I named the class .switch

Comment: Can we see the HTML that Jade generated?

Comment: @MarkRajcok sure, just updated the question with the HTML

Comment: `ng-switch="ng-switch"` seems to mess up ng-switch in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SBvcGG?p=preview) I'm trying this in (remove the `="ng-switch"` and it works).  Also, I don't think we want `on="$parent.displayType"`, but just `on="displayType"`.

Comment: Also, `ng-switch="displayType"` works, so you could probably use this Jade syntax: `.switch(ng-switch='displayType')`

Comment: @MarkRajcok yes it was a typo for the `$parent` remaining from some testing

Comment: @MarkRajcok OK that was it. jade generate a value equals to the attribute if not specified for the `ng-switch`, and it must have took precedence over the `on` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, `ng-switch="ng-switch"` was messing up ng-switch directive processing. `ng-switch="displayType"` works, so this Jade syntax should work:

```
.switch(ng-switch='displayType')
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue - my first fix was simply to enclose the "ng-switch on" in quotes in the .jade so that it is treated as a single attribute - otherwise it was translating to two separate html attributes.  To produce

```
<div ng-switch on="displayType" class="switch">
```

You would use

```
.switch("ng-switch on"="displayType")
```

but since the on is optional anyway (one could argue the sample in the docs is misleading to include it), the better way would be to omit the problematic "on" entirely (like the previous answer) like so:

```
.switch(ng-switch="displayType")
```

You can debug this sort of thing with [an online jade to html tool](http://html2jade.org/)